# Javascript Functions (from a closure)

Tags: javascript, closures

I have this code (given below) and when I write `c1 = count();` I call the function `count()` (my current understanding), so the closure will memorize c=1 after the first call.

Later, if I call `c1()` the result is 1. How comes that the result is 1, if when I called this function once by writing `c1=count()`, `c` was already incremented to 1? Shouldn't the value be 2?

```
function count() {
    var c = 0 ;
    return function() {
        c += 1 ;
        return c ;
    };
}
```

**If not,**

Why when I write this function, my output is 'A!'? That means that by writing `var x=a()` I call the function, the same logic should be used in the function above, shouldn't it?

```
function a() {
  alert('A!');
  return function() {
    alert('B!');
  };
};
var x = a();
```

Comment: *"I called this function once by writing: `c1=count()`"* -- no, you didn't. `count()`  and createsreturns an anonymous function that you store in `c1` but it doesn't call it. Then you call it using `c1()`.

Comment: I believe he wants to increment a number, but thinks that functions retain some sort of memory

Comment: In the second snippet you're just alerting `A` directly, there's no closure over any variable in `a` function. Calling `x()` alerts `B`.

Comment: @DMcCallum83 There is a sort of memory: the variable is stored in closure. Confusion seems to only regard to when function calls happen. Besides, I believe Claire is usually a  female name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is your function,

```
function count() {  
 var c = 0 ;
 return function() {
   c += 1 ;
   return c ;
 };
}
```

first time when you call the function `count()` it does 2 things,

1. Initialising var c
2. returns a function which contains a reference to the variable `c` which was declared in outer scope. (Learn more about closure: This is a good article https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36)

Now return value of `count()` i.e a return function is assigned to the variable `c1`. c1 is a function which when you call increments the value of variable `c`.

when you do,

```
var c1 = count(); // c = 0 & a function is assigned to c1
c1(); // c + 1 i.e 1
c1(); // c = 2
```

and so on..

Now next case,

```
function a() {
  alert('A!');
  return function() {
    alert('B!');
  };
};
var x = a();
```

when you call `a()`

1. `alert('A!')`
2. returns a function and assigning it to `x`;

next time when you call `x()` it will always `alert('B!')`

Hope this helps.

Comment: One more important thing about closures. If you'll assign the result of `count` for a second time, to another variable, this call will create a new closure, and `c1` calls will continue to count `c` from its current value, i.e. it is not reset.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `count`  then you return the inner function from `count` which you store in  `c1`:

```
return function() {
  c += 1 ;
  return c ;
};
```

But at that time you haven't called that returned function, so `c` is still `0`.

When you now call the returned function you stored in `c1` by writing `c1` then `c` is incremented by `1`, so for the first call of `c1` you get `1`.

```js
function count() {
  console.log('var c=0')
  var c = 0;


  console.log('return function () { ...  }')
  return function() {
    console.log('c += 1')
    c += 1;
    console.log('return c')
    return c;
  };
}

console.log('var c1 = count()')
var c1 = count();

console.log('c1()')
console.log(c1())
console.log('c1()')
console.log(c1())
```

Comment: What happens when I have only this :  c1 = count(); ?

Comment: @Claire `c=0` and the return of the function you define within `count` but that function is not called at that time. Check the logs messages of the runnable snippet.

Comment: So that means that in the second function if i do : x(), the result will be 'B!' ?

Comment: @Claire Well, what does it show if you do so? I mean it would be faster to test that your self then asking it as a question.

Answer (score -1):

```
function count() {

   var c = 0 ;
   return function() {
     c += 1 ;
     return c ;
    };
}
```

Every time you call that function, you set the value to 0 - so it's alway going to return one.  Instead call it increment count, and pass the value to be incremented in:

```
function incrementCount(valToInc) {
   return valToInc += 1;
}

incrementCount(4); //returns 5
```

Comment: No, it won't be always `1`. The call of `count`  will return a function  and never `1`, and if you then call this returned function, it will increment `c` every time it is called: [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhgp8rcn/)